# NHibernate, MySQL, Windows Server 2003 -- connection problems

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2003

We're using MySQL (5.0.x) on Windows, in an ASP.NET MVC app.  Recently, we started using NHibernate in a lot of places, and it works great in the ASP.NET app.

On Vista and Windows Server 2008, it still works great everywhere.  We've also got a couple command-line tools that use the same codebase, and they work everywhere *except* on our Windows Server 2003 boxes (otherwise identical to the WS2K8 in every way we can imagine).  It seems to be having trouble making connections:

```
TIMESTAMP_HERE [1] WARN  NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at Our.Common.Services.OurConnectionProvider.GetConnection() inc:\OUR_CODE\blah...\OurConnectionProvider.cs:line 99
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenConnection()
```

Does this sound familiar to anybody?  Is there any way in which W2K3 would be different from W2K8/Vista that would affect NHibernate making connections to MySQL?

Comment: Fix found: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,228953,228986

Comment: Ahhh.... The eternal problems with ephemeral ports.... http://www.danielschneller.com/2006/09/windows-tcp-port-conflicts-above-1024.html, http://www.danielschneller.com/2007/10/cant-start-server-bind-on-tcpip-port-no.html and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45021 might be of interest.