# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts in NHibernate, MySql

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

One of the client is reporting this issue happening in our application. NHibernate throws `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts` in the middle of the app running, so it is not a mistake in the configuration. It happens randomly, but always when the transaction is opened.

I saw this: 
[NHibernate, MySQL, Windows Server 2003 -- connection problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936486/nhibernate-mysql-windows-server-2003-connection-problems)
But the server in my case is Windows 2008. And app opens only single connection simultaneously. MySQL version is 5.5.28. Server is on the remove machine

Unfortunately the app requires the HW I do not have, and I cannot reproduce it locally.
Any ideas or directions I need to dig in?

Comment: can you post your connection string too please? without password ;)

Comment: It's `Server=SRV;Port=3310;Database=AP;Uid=user;Pwd=....`

Comment: is SRV an ip address, server name or fully qualified domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting using the full directory name, e.g. instead of Server=SRV use

```
Server=SRV.yournetwork.com
```

It might be that is has trouble resolving the server name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, that didn't help

Comment: to rule things out, maybe try ip address if you can. and how come you're not using the default port number?

Comment: Not sure. This app is used at the customer side, and it's their rules. But please notice, that the app works most of the time, and the error happen randomly, after 10-15 minutes of app working. I believe it should be something more complicated. One additional interesting thing about it: customer says that he tried different DB servers, both remote and local - and both fails. App is a framework and there are a lot of projects build on top of it, but this one is the first to reproduce this issue